# Как сделать закачку со своего сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование

Хочу сделать так, чтоб с моего сайта люди могли скачивать файлы и закачивать свои.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужна таблица для хранения имен загружаемых файлов, ну и скрипт отдачи файла по запросу, допустим, по его `ID` при закачке.

Comment: а что лучше использовать javascript или php?

Comment: Для начала понять что такое JS и PHP. Это разные вещи, php это серверный язык программирования, JS это клиентский.
<br>
использовать придется PHP+MySql - для того чтобы быстро находить закачанные файлы. HTML+CSS чтобы красиво оформить все на страничке.

Answer (score 0):

Имена файлов хранить в базе, когда пользователь запрашивает файл - формировать путь, через header подсовывать все это дело пользователю